# How to apply same processing pipeline for train and test data when they result in different final features

Tags: machine-learning, regression, one-hot-encoding, data-processing, imputation

I'm trying to create a regression model to predict some housing sales and I am facing an issue with processing the train data and test data (this is not the validation data taken from the training set itself) the same way. The steps I'm performing for the processing are follows:

1. drop the columns with null values >50%
2. Impute the rest of the columns containing null values
3. One-hot encode the categorical columns

Say my train data has the following columns (after label extraction) (the ones in ** ** contain null values):

```
['col1', 'col2', '**col3**', 'col4', '**col5**', 'col6', '**col7**','**col8**', '**col9**', '**col10**', 'col11']
```

test data has the following columns:

```
['col1', '**col2**', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', '**col7**', '**col8**', '**col9**', '**col10**', 'col11']
```

I only drop those columns with >50% null values and the rest of the columns in bold, I impute. Say, in the train data, I will have:

```
cols_to_drop= ['**col3**','**col5**','**col7**' ]
cols_to_impute= ['**col8**', '**col9**','**col10**' ]
```

And if I retain the same columns to be dropped from test data too, my test data will have the following:

```
cols_to_drop= ['**col3**','**col5**','**col7**' ]
cols_to_impute= ['**col2**', '**col8**', '**col9**','**col10**' ]
```

The problem now comes with imputation where I have to `.fit_transform` my imputer with the `cols_to_impute` in train data and have to `.transform` the same imputer with the `cols_to_impute` in the test data since there is a clear difference in the number of features supplied here in both the `cols_to_impute` lists. (I did this as well and had issues with imputation)

Say, if I keep the same `cols_to_impute` in both train and test datasets ignoring the null column `**col2**` of test data, I faced an issue when it came to one-hot encoding saying `Nan's` need to be handled before encoding. So, how should the processing be done for train and test sets in such cases? Should I be concatenating both of them, perform processing and split them later again? I read about leakage issues in doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should do the following:

1. Combine both `train` and `test` dataframe, then do the first two steps i.e. dropping the column with nulls and imputing them.
2. Then, split it back into `train` and `test`, then do one hot encoding.

This would ensure that both the data frames have same columns and there is no leakage in doing one hot encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest, but I'm wondering if imputing the test data columns along with the train data columns (because, concatenation) will lead to test data acquiring some pattern from the training data? Will that be an issue?

Comment: good question, ideally it shouldn't since test and train data are expected to come from same distributions (means having similar mean, median etc.)